# How to remove the push transition border in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, transition

[image: push segue border]

I want to remove the transition border when pushing a new view controller to the navigation controller. How do I do that in Objective C?

Answer (score 0):

You should create our own transition, take a look for example here:

http://www.teehanlax.com/blog/custom-uiviewcontroller-transitions/

[image]

other links:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/110536/custom-uiviewcontroller-transitions
https://www.objc.io/issues/5-ios7/view-controller-transitions/